# Imaged cropped on background header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add an image on my background however this image is not showing the full info I need.

Can someone help me to get the right dimension x size?

Thanks in advance.

[image: intended output]

```css
#hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75vh;
    background: url("../img/hero-bannertest3.jpeg") top center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

Comment: Please create a codesnippet here.  At the moment, its impossible to know what you mean.  You havent specified what it looks like and what it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hope this will solved your problem

```
#hero {
   width: 100%;
   height: 75vh;
   background-image: url("../img/hero-bannertest3.jpeg");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```